# Why allow humans to import guns?

Tags: the-matrix

According to [Writing Secure Code](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/writing-secure-code/fgqpf3h0qn85?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab):

> you should not trust data until the data is validated. Failure to do
>   so will render your application vulnerable. Or, put another way: all
>   input is evil until proven otherwise. That’s rule number one.

The Zion rebels are hackers or rogue users that the machines try to stop using the Agents. Why allow them to bring in weapons from the construct into the Matrix? In other words, the rogue users input (guns) are evil until proven otherwise. Can't the machines write code that will validate what is being brought in and remove any unwanted items?

In the matrix world, they could even prohibit guns from being constructed or used, so even bluepills can't make them. The only entities that would have them are the Agents.

Comment: Perhaps the validation wasn't flawless? Seems like a normal day in a software developesr live.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid - These are machines, they created the Matrix

Comment: The machines were created by men. The Matrix was far from flawless (see the whole point of the Architect). Wrong data validation seems like a small bug in the entirety of the whole.

Comment: The only way to get truly secure code is using formal methods.  Formal methods are a kind of math.  And [the universe doesn't run on math.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3822/5930).  :-)  (But seriously, this is a universe in which the Chosen One can take over control of hostile machines with nothing but the force of his willpower.  We're clearly not talking buffer overflows here.)

Answer (score 8):

You seem to be missing the fundamental purpose of the Zionese Rebellion. Within the system itself, Zion acts as a ['honeypot'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_(computing)). The ability to enter the Matrix and the capacity to upload and download data to and from the Matrix itself (including guns and bombs) **must be part of the system that the machines have *allowed* to occur**, presumably in order to keep human malcontents happy and engaged until it's time to kill them all and reboot the system with a new cadre of rebels.

As to *why* they don't make it so that only Agents can have guns, this is addressed in the first film. The world of the Matrix is based on physical rules that apply equally to all parties. Guns work because the rules allow them to work.

> **Morpheus:** *I’ve seen an agent punch through a concrete wall. Men have emptied entire clips at them and hit nothing but air. Yet their
>   strength and their speed are still based in a world that is built on
>   rules. Because of that, they will never be as strong or as fast as you
>   can be.*

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Valorum's in-universe explanation, consider that an [automated validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) of software is impossible. So if users can use a reasonably powerful language for their inputs, no machine can validate it. The way around that would be a less powerful language, making the Matrix much more limited.